# ResourceT, MonadTrans instance not available

Tags: haskell

Running *Linux Mint 17.2 Rafaela* and *GHC 7.8.4* with *ResourceT 1.1.6*, I was trying to write a simple "Hello World":

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Resource
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class

main = runResourceT $ lift (putStrLn "Hello, World!")
```

but:

```
No instance for (Control.Monad.Trans.Class.MonadTrans
                   Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.Internal.ResourceT)
  arising from a use of ‘Control.Monad.Trans.Class.lift’
In the second argument of ‘(GHC.Base.$)’, namely
  ‘Control.Monad.Trans.Class.lift
     (System.IO.putStrLn "Hello, World!")’
In the expression:
  Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.runResourceT
  GHC.Base.$
    Control.Monad.Trans.Class.lift (System.IO.putStrLn "Hello, World!")
In an equation for ‘Main.main’:
    Main.main
      = Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.runResourceT
        GHC.Base.$
          Control.Monad.Trans.Class.lift (System.IO.putStrLn "Hello, World!")
```

As the error message shows, the `MonadTrans ResourceT` thing is not defined but it is clearly defined in the [Control.Monad.Trans.Resource](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/resourcet-1.1.6/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Resource.html) module and it is imported!

A little more strange thing is that inspecting the module in ghci:

```
Prelude Control.Monad.Trans.Resource Control.Monad.Trans.Class> :i ResourceT 
type role ResourceT representational nominal
newtype ResourceT (m :: * -> *) a
  = Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.Internal.ResourceT {Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.Internal.unResourceT :: GHC.IORef.IORef
                                                                                                            Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.Internal.ReleaseMap
                                                                                                          -> m a}
    -- Defined in ‘Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.Internal’
instance [safe] Monad m => Monad (ResourceT m)
  -- Defined in ‘Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.Internal’
instance [safe] Functor m => Functor (ResourceT m)
  -- Defined in ‘Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.Internal’
instance [safe] (MonadThrow m, Control.Monad.Base.MonadBase IO m,
                 transformers-0.3.0.0:Control.Monad.IO.Class.MonadIO m,
                 Control.Applicative.Applicative m) =>
                MonadResource (ResourceT m)
  -- Defined in ‘Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.Internal’
instance [safe] MonadBaseControl b m =>
                MonadBaseControl b (ResourceT m)
  -- Defined in ‘Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.Internal’
instance [safe] MonadThrow m => MonadThrow (ResourceT m)
  -- Defined in ‘Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.Internal’
```

And as it shows there is no `MonadTrans ResourceT` thing even there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely you have two copies of the transformers package installed (you can test that with `ghc-pkg list transformers`). I wrote a blog post detailing this at:

http://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2014/09/woes-multiple-package-versions

My recommendation: install your packages with [Stack](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack#readme) and then run your file with `stack runghc yourfile.hs`, which will ensure a consistent set of packages.

Comment: Thank you, it was the problem

/opt/ghc/7.8.4/lib/ghc-7.8.4/package.conf.d
   transformers-0.3.0.0
/home/bandbaz/.ghc/x86_64-linux-7.8.4/package.conf.d
   transformers-0.4.3.0